# Do we need to specify the cardinality of a relation when we create a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Do we need to specify whether the table is one-to-one, or many-to-one, or one-to-many, or many-to-many when we create an SQL schema physically in the database? We can show this in E/R diagram...

If so, what keywords do we add to `CREATE TABLE....`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not something you need to specify, it can be inferred by the indexes/constraints on the fields your foreign keys are defined on.  For example, if it's joining two tables based on their Primary key, it's obviously a One-to-One relationship.  If it's a one-to-many relationship, there won't be any unique constraints on the "many" side.

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you mean it but we define it by creating relationships like foreign keys to identify and specify the relationships among the tables. More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).